# Running a Gulp Task inside the Watch Task

Tags: gulp

I have the following Gulp Watch Task.

```
// Watch function
function watch() {
    // browserSync.init({
    //     proxy: 'localhost/Unice/html'
    // });
    gulp.watch('assets/scss/**.*scss', style);
    gulp.watch('./*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('assets/css/**.css').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}
```

I have another task which converts SCSS to css as follows

```
//scss to css
function style() {
    return gulp.src('assets/scss/**/*.scss', { sourcemaps: true })
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css', { sourcemaps: '.' }))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
}
```

How can I run the `style` task automatically when running the `watch` command if I make modifications to any SCSS files.

Comment: Correct the glob in your watch task to `'assets/scss/**/*.scss'`.

Comment: @TheDancingCode please write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glob in your `watch` task contains an error and should be:

```js
gulp.watch('assets/scss/**/*.scss', style);
```